# Group by function in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort data by using the GROUP BY function. My query works fine until I add this to it. Here it is:

```
SELECT a.cust_id, a.account_id, a.product_cd, status, b.name, i.fname, i.lname, 
from account a, branch b, individual i
where b.name = 'So. NH Branch' or b.name = 'Woburn Branch' and a.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by b.name;
```

I get this message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from account a, branch b, individual i
where b.name = 'So. NH Branch' or b.name ' at line 2

Comment: Do you realize that you are doing a cartesian product on your tables?

Comment: (I wonder what the rational for the short cross join syntax was ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT a.cust_id, 
  a.account_id, 
  a.product_cd, 
  status, 
  b.name, 
  i.fname, 
  i.lname, 
         ^ --- this is incorrect.
```

One thing that I do see that is strange with your query is you are not joining your tables, you are returning a cartesian result set.

If you do not want a cartesian result set, then you would use a `JOIN` between the tables. Similar to this:

```
SELECT a.cust_id, 
   a.account_id, 
   a.product_cd, 
   status, 
   b.name, 
   i.fname, 
   i.lname
from account a
INNER JOIN branch b
  ON a.branchid = b.id
INNER JOIN individual i
  ON a.individualid = i.id
where b.name = 'So. NH Branch' or b.name = 'Woburn Branch' and a.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by b.name;
```

*Note: I guessed on the column names that would join the tables.*

Comment: Does OP really want to produce a cartesian product?

Comment: @njk probably not, but I was adding those details to my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't what you select be in the group by or a aggregate_function?

Comment: Sometimes it just helps to have an extra pair of eyes.

Comment: @SElizabethStarkey happy to help. :)  Since you are new to StackOverflow, if you find any of the answers to your questions helpful, then be sure to accept an answer via the checkmark to the left of it.  If will help future visitors to the site and you will get site reputation for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

In addition the erroneous comma pointed out by bluefeet, you are producing a cartesian product. This may not be what you want. You need to associate the tables somehow (illustration only):

```
SELECT a.cust_id, 
       a.account_id, 
       a.product_cd, 
       status, 
       b.name, 
       i.fname, 
       i.lname 
FROM   account a, 
       branch b, 
       individual i 
WHERE  i.cust_id = a.cust_id             <-- JOIN individual to account
       AND b.account_id = a.account_id   <-- JOIN branch to individual
       AND b.name = 'So. NH Branch' 
        OR b.name = 'Woburn Branch' 
           AND a.status = 'ACTIVE' 
GROUP  BY b.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers regarding cartesian product and the erroneous comma, if you're just trying to sort the data you should use `ORDER BY` as opposed to `GROUP BY` as the latter is only necessary when using aggregate functions.